# HttpURLConnection POST request - cannot send data to server

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have this code:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
conn.setRequestMethod(type);
conn.setDoOutput(output);
if(output)
   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setDoInput(true);

conn.connect();

OutputStream out = null;
if(output)
   out = conn.getOutputStream();
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

if(output) {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
    bw.write(getQuery(params));
    bw.flush();
}

// Get output
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append("\n");
}

in.close();
if(output)
    out.close();

// Do stuff with the output
```

This code throws an IOException when `output` is true (doing a POST or PUT request), and doesn't complete the request. I've tried reordering the `conn.connect()`, write call, and stream creation blocks, but no permutation worked.

In all cases, the BufferedReader works just fine and doesn't throw any exceptions. `getQuery` correctly returns a URL-encoded string.

Here's the stack trace from the IOException:

```
java.io.IOException: closed
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:129)
W/System.err﹕ at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBytes(OutputStreamWriter.java:167)
W/System.err﹕ at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:158)
W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:124)
W/System.err﹕ at org.project.NetworkHelper.doRequest(NetworkHelper.java:57)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What ends up happening is that the request goes through, but none of the POST or PUT data ends up at the server - it's like the write call never happened.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You've complicated the code.
Here's a sample for `openConnection()` implementation.

```
        byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(request);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    Integer.toString(postDataLength));
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.write(postData);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                        httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
                //get output
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Customs.mToast(context, "Server down! Try after some time");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```